# Trouble accessing RTC memory address for ADC configuration on ESP-32 through Arduino

Tags: memory, arduino, hardware, esp32, adc

Using an ESP-32's ADC I need to set the sample cycles for both ADC_1 and ADC_2 to run the fastest possible. In the older Espressif toolchain (1.0.6) support was still not added for direct Cycle control through Arduino. I cannot use the more modern toolchain because of a different problem that pops out with the ADC sample rate.

The Espressif reference manual for the ESP-32 shows the RTC address for the ADC1 in the following [chart](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_technical_reference_manual_en.pdf#subsection.29.5). The same is true for ADC2. The complete register [summary](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_technical_reference_manual_en.pdf#subsection.29.6) shows that both addresses have both Read and Write access so one should be able to modify them directly accessing the memory address. The address is handled as RTC memory (not Data RAM); does this mean I cannot access it the usual way?

At the moment I have tried accessing the address through pointers (i.e.):

```
unsigned int ADC_1_CONFIG_ADDRESS = 0x60002610;
unsigned int *ptr;
//...

setup(){
  ptr = (unsigned int*)&ADC_1_CONFIG_ADDRESS;
  *ptr = (*ptr | 0xFFFFFFE7) + 0x10;;
  //...
}
```

This code should modify the APB_SARADC_WORK_MODE from single to alternate mode. I have not seen any changes using this code. Even when changing all values to `0xFFFFFFFF` or `0x00000000` expecting to get different sample rates to the default ones I haven't got any changes.

There are two places where I know my mistake is; either I'm writing in the wrong memory address or I'm missing some info regarding "when" to write to that memory address (before/after ADC_START, before/after pin attach, etc.)

EDIT:

After much reading the documentation I believe the correct way to set the complete config for one of the ADCs would be more or less the next one.

```
  //int DIR = 0x60002600;
  int DIR = 0x3FF48800;
  int *DIR_ADC_1;
  DIR_ADC_1 = (int*)&DIR;
  *(DIR_ADC_1 + 0) = 0x00; //Less significant
  *(DIR_ADC_1 + 1) = 0xFF;
  *(DIR_ADC_1 + 2) = 0xFF;
  *(DIR_ADC_1 + 3) = 0xFF; //Most significant

  *(DIR_ADC_1 + 0x18 + 0) = 0x00;
  *(DIR_ADC_1 + 0x18 + 1) = 0x00;
  *(DIR_ADC_1 + 0x18 + 2) = 0x00;
  *(DIR_ADC_1 + 0x18 + 3) = 0x00;

  *(DIR_ADC_1 + 0x2c + 1) = 0x03;
```

However, all my results and speeds have been equal to the default settings.

Am I just writing to the wrong addresses? I can't seem to alter the behavior of the ADC or the ULC.